# What kind of a Polaroid 600-camera is this?

Tags: film, old-cameras, polaroid, instant-camera

[image: unknown Polaroid 600]

Please help me with this! I know it's a Polaroid 600 'cause the model and the film it uses. It has a yellow "live for the moment" logo in front of the cam (see the pic) and behind the flashbar. Also has the Polaroid-logo on top of the flashbar. Does not have a tripod socket.

Answer (score 4):

It would seem to be a standard Polaroid 600 in a colour that [this dude on flickr refers to as `Party Blue`](https://m.flickr.com/#/photos/donaldtang/sets/72157631443995742/). Indeed [searching for `Polaroid 600 Party Blue` on Google yields many results showing that camera.](https://www.google.fr/search?q=polaroid%20600%20party%20blue&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=EnuMVfSxM4urUdbdj7gM&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=360&bih=567&dpr=3) [According to the Polaroid page on the Camerapedia wiki it belongs to the Polaroid 600 One Step Flash (Close Up) family](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Polaroid_Integral_600_Series) and it is indeed known under the `Polaroid Party` denomination:

> - Polaroid Party (blue with yellow details; pale and dark green)

For completeness sake, [quoting from Camerapedia](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Polaroid_Integral_600_Series) its specifications are:

> ### Specifications
>
> - Lens: 116mm, f/11, Single-element plastic.
> - Fixed focus (sharpest at 4-5 feet), but with sliding close-up attachment.
> - Shutter: electronic; automatic speed between 1/4-1/200 sec.
> - Integral auto flash that works in low light but cannot be forced on or off.
> - Polaroid's Light Management System (the darken/lighten exposure correction slider).

Answer (score 0):

Think they just referred to that as the Polaroid One-Step camera. Just happens to be a different version of it with colored plastic.

Comment: It's actually closer to the Sun600 LMS then the OneStep600. I have both on my shelf and can confirm :)